# mysql version 5.5.31 load data infile syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, cloud

I am trying to load a file into mysql table on the cloud host but it's throwing me an syntax error. my mysql version is 5.5.31.

> mysql -u ykd202 -p -e 'LOAD DATA INFILE "home/folks/kosh/intx.csv" into TABLE  history COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATE BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;' f2014

In above statement f2014 is database name. and the error I am getting is

```
Enter password:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' optinally enclosed by ' escaped by ' lines terminated by n ignore 1 lines' at line 1
```

Comment: `optinally enclosed by` that part of the error doesn't match your code, so it's hard to say if you pasted the actual error, or typed it in yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You posted the following for code:

```
mysql -u ykd202 -p -e 'LOAD DATA INFILE "home/folks/kosh/intx.csv" into TABLE history COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATE BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;' f2014
```

However, your error message is contradicting itself:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' optinally enclosed by ' escaped by ' lines terminated by n ignore 1 lines' at line 1

1a) Part of the error: `optinally enclosed by` - mispelled "optinally", it should be "optionally".

1b) Part of your code: `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`

*then*...

2a) Part of error: `lines terminated by n` and

2b) Part of your code: `LINES TERMINATE BY '\n'` - missing a `D` at the end of TERMINATE which should read as TERMINATED.

So I will go off on a limb here and say that you need to modify your code as:

```
mysql -u ykd202 -p -e 'LOAD DATA INFILE "home/folks/kosh/intx.csv" into TABLE history COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;' f2014
```

---

- [**Read the manual on the subject**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

---

**Edit:**

Try also:

```
mysql -u ykd202 -p -e "LOAD DATA INFILE 'home/folks/kosh/intx.csv' into TABLE history COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;" f2014
```

Comment: I have tried the above code but still throw's me an error saying
    ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ' ESCAPED BY ' LINES TERMINATED BY n IGNORE 1 LINES' at line.
I typed the exact code which you gave me

Comment: @Yash Are you doing this via command line?

Comment: @Yash Try changing `COLUMNS TERMINATED BY` to `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` - see if that helps.

Comment: @Yash I made a slight change. Reload and look under **Edit: Try also:**

Comment: this is cloud host which I am using through putty on windows.

Comment: @Yash Ok. Well, unfortunately I don't know anything about cloud host or putty. Wish I could be of more help.

Comment: I tried the above code and this time its shows me some other error i.e
ERROR 1083 (42000) at line 1: Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual

Comment: @Yash Seems it has something to do with how the fields are seperated as.

Comment: Thanks!!!! will search more on thi